# How can I connect to my own Git server in SourceTree?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, bitbucket-server

I have a Git server. However, when I try to add a user to SourceTree, I see that I can add only GitHub, Bitbucket and Stash accounts. How I can run it with my own server?

Answer (score 12):

You can add a repository by URL by going to File -> New/Clone and choosing "+ New Repository", then "Clone from URL".

This is on Mac SourceTree 2.0+

[image: example]

Comment: I believe the OP has asked how to connect accounts and not how to clone a single repo. ( deduction from the `I see that I can add only GitHub, Bitbucket and Stash accounts` part of the original Q )

Comment: The answer shows that it's not possible to do as the original question is, and offers a practical alternative that works.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe this is a little different on the Windows version of Sourcetree. As mentioned in the previous answer, start with File > Clone/New.

Add your repo details in "Source Path / URL:"

[image]

and then "Clone". Once the connection is established, you will be prompted for the credentials.

Comment: This answer is on how to clone a repo, and not on how to connect account from own git server.

Comment: The answer shows that it's not possible to do as the original question is, and offers a practical alternative that works.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is older, but this is what I had to do to connect to my companies git server and have access to the Sourcetree/GUI features. We use SSH to connect but should work with HTTP:// and HTTPS:// connections.

when cloning the repository put the correctly formatted following into the clone url input: `{protocol}://{username}:{password}@{url to get server}/{path to repository}`

Sourcetree will prompt for password, enter it, and you may choose to save the password. or not, i think its checked by default... and then make sure the rest of the set up is correct and what you need and and it should be good :)

Comment: This indeed works, but it's not a real connection of accounts like you would get with other providers ( for example listing existing repos or starting a new one ) also some `CredentialHelperSelector` is popping up all the time - not sure why ( Using sourcetree 3.4.4 )